# MySQL Query Produces an Empty Set

Tags: mysql

I've got a mySQL query that produces an empty set. For example,

```
SELECT id 
FROM `my_table` 
WHERE type = 'old'
AND neighborhoods = 'Newport'
```

produces an empty set. In the event that the query produces an empty set is it possible to have it return:

```
id
---
0
```

Thank you.

-Laxmidi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add in a `COUNT` part of the query

```
SELECT id, COUNT(id) as Total 
FROM `my_table` 
WHERE type = 'old'
AND neighborhoods = 'Newport'
```

And that will return at least one record with `Total=0`

Comment: I left id, and COUNT() as the parameters so you will either get a result of "0" or you will get the record set.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

```
SELECT COUNT(id) 
FROM `my_table` 
WHERE type = 'old'
AND neighborhoods = 'Newport'
```

Will always returns a result set.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the INCLUDE the id then you can use LEFT OUTER to accomplish this.

```
SELECT a.id,
       IFNULL(b.cnt,0) as cnt
FROM
(
  SELECT distinct id, 'myjoin' as myjoin
  FROM `my_table` 
  WHERE id = [what you are looking for]
) a LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
  SELECT COUNT(id) as cnt 
  FROM `my_table` 
  WHERE type = 'old'
  AND neighborhoods = 'Newport'
) b ON a.myjoin=b.myjoin
```

The first query brings back the id you want then joins (LEFT OUTER) that to a fixed value (called 'myjoin' in this case) and will bring back 0 if the latter query comes back empty.